# how to send my value to my database

Tags: php, database, input, insert

hello I want to insert my value to the database here my structure .

```
<tr>
        <td>
            <b>Vendredi</b> </br><?php echo $date6 ?>
                </td>

        <td>
                <input size="10" type="text" id="projvendredi" name="projvendredi"onkeypress="return handleEnter6(event, this, 'task');"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="clientvendredi" class = "client" size="12" id ="clientvendredi" disabled />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="projdesvendredi" size="30" class "desc" id ="projdesvendredi"disabled />
        </td>

        <td>
        <span id="calculTemps5">

            <input  id="input6" class= "temps"  type="number" name="tempsv" size="2" min="0" max="24" value="0" /></br>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

and here my button

```
    <input type="text" id="result" readonly="readonly" name="total" />

<input type="submit"  value="Terminé" id="end" />
<input type="hidden" name="data" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" />

</p>
</form>
```

Here is my insert.php

```
$date = $_POST['data'] ;
 if (isSet($_POST['descprojsam']))
 {
    $descprojsam = $_POST['descprojsam'] ;
    echo($descprojsam);
}

echo($date);

// Connect to the DB
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","cruel") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));


    // adding new recherche
    if(!empty($_POST['descprojsam'])) 
    {


        $sql = "    INSERT INTO `projetstaches`(`prtId`, `prtTimeSheetId`, `prtProjetNum`, `prtDate`, `prtTaskId`, `prtTime`, `prtLocation`, `prtDescription`) 
        ([value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4],[value-5],[value-6],[value-7],'$descprojsam')";
            $link->query($sql);
        }


?>
```

I've not finish my insert cause i don't know how really to do it. I have 7 days so I gave you my friday for exemple.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is case sensative, `isSet($_POST['descprojsam'])` should be `isset($_POST['descprojsam'])`

Comment: with that I'm able now to add it in my database?